# Firefox not prompting me for master password

Tags: firefox

I set up a master password but it didn't seem to do anything I can still autologin without it, and in fact haven't been prompted once

Comment: Would probably be better to use a password manager than using a browser.  Lastpass, Keepass, and or Bitwarren are a few.

Answer (score 2):

The master password is not required to launch Firefox, only for specific security-related issues involving your user profile, such as looking up a saved password, or connecting through Firefox Sync (TY, https://askubuntu.com/users/20358/jpaugh , for noting that).

Comment: Specifically, it's needed to sync your Firefox account or enter a saved password. FF asks me to input my master password almost immediately, but that's because I use Sync.